# finding the start day (Monday) of the current week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Looking for a SQL query/queries that would determine the start day (Monday) of the current week.

Example: 
If today is -> then the start of the week is

```
Sat Oct 09, 2010 -> Start of the week is Monday Oct 04, 2010
Sun Oct 10, 2010 -> Start of the week is Monday Oct 04, 2010
Mon Oct 11, 2010 -> Start of the week is Monday Oct 11, 2010
Tue Oct 12, 2010 -> Start of the week is Monday Oct 11, 2010
```

I have seen many "solutions" on Google and StackOverflow. The look something like:

```
SET @pInputDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @pInputDate, 111)
SELECT DATEADD(DD, 1 - DATEPART(DW, @pInputDate), @pInputDate)
```

This fails because:
Sun Oct 10, 2010 -> start of week Monday Oct 11, 2010 (which is incorrect).

Comment: Do you need to find only Monday or the first working day of the week?

Comment: I want the start of the week (Monday) regardless whether it's a working day or a holiday.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try using [`DATEFIRST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) to explicitly set the day of week to be regarded as the 'first'.

```
set DATEFIRST 1  --Monday
select DATEADD(DD, 1 - DATEPART(DW, @pInputDate), @pInputDate)
```

This will return the Monday of the week the InputDate falls in.

Comment: I found another solution, but this one is a lot simpler and cleaner.  Thank you.

Comment: how can we make it to find last to last week Monday ? I tried to make 2- in expression instead of 1- , but no luck . Any suggestions?

Comment: for last day of the week use 7 in date add
set DATEFIRST 1  --Monday
select DATEADD(DD, 7 - DATEPART(DW, @pInputDate), @pInputDate)

Answer (score 11):

The most simple implementation

`SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) MondayOfCurrentWeek`

Answer (score 10):

Building on top of p.campbell's solution, if you don't want to use or can't use "SET DATEFIRST 1", you can get around that by doing the following:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DD, 2 - DATEPART(DW, DATEADD(DD, -1, @pInputDate)), DATEADD(DD, -1, @pInputDate))
```

Comment: Thanks, this single SQL statement worked a treat for me in SAP Universe Object Definition. Identifying the week beginning date allowed me aggregate for weekly runchart plot.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use DATEFIRST:

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)     -- Monday of current week
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()) - 1, 0) -- Monday of last week
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()) + 1, 0) -- Monday of next week

SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) + 4 -- Friday of current week
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DATEFIRST. Without it your code always assigns Sunday to "wrong" week:

```sql
    SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,'2020-10-11'), 0) --> Sunday -> 2020-10-12
    SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,'2020-10-12'), 0) --> Monday -> 2020-10-12
    SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,'2020-10-18'), 0) --> Sunday -> 2020-10-19
```

In this case 2 factors needs to be taken care of:

1. `@@DATEFIRST` value
2. What day your weeks starts on (for me it is Monday)

E.g.: all below lines produce 2020-10-12 (Monday for week starting on Monday, 2020-10-12 and ending on Sunday, 2020-10-18) regardless of `@@DATEFIRST` value:

```sql
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -((@@DATEFIRST + 7 - (2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2020-10-12')) % 7) % 7), '2020-10-12')
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -((@@DATEFIRST + 7 - (2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2020-10-13')) % 7) % 7), '2020-10-13')
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -((@@DATEFIRST + 7 - (2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2020-10-14')) % 7) % 7), '2020-10-14')
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -((@@DATEFIRST + 7 - (2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2020-10-15')) % 7) % 7), '2020-10-15')
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -((@@DATEFIRST + 7 - (2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2020-10-16')) % 7) % 7), '2020-10-16')
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -((@@DATEFIRST + 7 - (2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2020-10-17')) % 7) % 7), '2020-10-17')
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -((@@DATEFIRST + 7 - (2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2020-10-18')) % 7) % 7), '2020-10-18')
```