# SQL-Automatically Bucketize all dates into that weeks monday date-

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-update

all- I'm looking to automatically standardize a certain date field into the monday date of that week. Essentially, if an entry came in with a date in this field of Tuesday, July 30th, 2013- I would want to standardize it to Monday, July 30th, 2013. I'd like to be able to apply this to only dates in a certain column where entries may have more than one date in seperate columns.

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you mean you want Tuesday July 30 to be Monday, July 29?  Always the previous monday, or would Sunday become the next day?

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936844/finding-the-start-day-monday-of-the-current-week

Comment: The week is Sunday-Saturday, so a Sunday would convert to the NEXT monday (the next day)- any other day would revert to previous Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Monday of the current week you can use the following in SQL Server:

```
SELECT DateAdd (Day, 2 - DatePart (dw, YourDate), YourDate)
```

Depending on desired behavior, you may have to use `SET DATEFIRST 2` to adjust the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<myRecord>> recordList = new List<<myRecord>>();
List<DateTime> mondays = new List<DateTime>();
DateTime first = new DateTime(2013, 1, 30);
DateTime last = new DateTime(2013, 7, 29);

for (Date mon = first; mon <= last; mon = mon.AddDays(7)) {
    recordList.Add(new List<myRecord>([SELECT * FROM myRecord WHERE myRecord.Date >= mon AND myRecord.Date < mon.AddDays(7)] ))
}

foreach (List<myRecord> monList : recordList) {
    //do stuff with each monday bucket
}
```

dunno what technology youre using but maybe something like this would work?