# Date variable from Monday till Monday with time 8:00

Tags: sql-server, date, variables

how to create two variables with a date for the procedure, regardless of when it starts:
1st variable - 8:00 of the last Monday
2nd variable - 8:00 of the last but one Monday (i.e. the difference between the variables is a week)

I have tried this, but it shows time 00:00

SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 0)

SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 7)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Do any of these answers help? [Get first day of week in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7168874/1048425), or  [finding the start day (Monday) of the current week](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3936844/1048425) or [SQL Server : get next relative day of week. (Next Monday, Tuesday, Wed…)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18920393/1048425)

Comment: I have tried this, but it shows time 00:00, I need 8:00SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 0)

 


SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this answer your question, but the below returns the date in european format with 8 AM as time. If you need the american format, you might need to change the dateadd() function.

A bit nested, but have a look if this helps

EDIT: Made it simpler and modified your initial code as well.

```
set DATEFIRST 1 --Monday

select

cast(concat(convert(varchar,dateadd(dd,1 - datepart(dw,getdate()),getdate()),101),' 8:00') as datetime)
,cast(concat(convert(varchar,dateadd(dd,1 - datepart(dw,getdate()),getdate()+7),101),' 8:00') as datetime)
```

See if this works.