# Group By Week Date when start of week is Monday

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to group the `ownerid` and `Yes` & `No` counts by week date. I get the following week numbers for each line with the below code, in the next step however I am having trouble figuring out how to group by week date instead of week number.  I attempted to use `DATEADD(Week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, i.createdon), 0)` under GROUP BY but receive an error. `@@DATEFIRST is set to 1 for Monday.`

Sample Data:

| owneridname | createdon | svb_contactname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 2023-06-18 14:14:09.000 | Mike Ossoff |
| Michael grant | 2023-06-20 14:48:24.000 | Third Party |
| Josh Gardner | 2023-06-22 10:35:49.000 | NULL |
| Elizabeth Smith | 2023-06-22 16:54:23.000 | NULL |
| Emma Marks | 2023-06-22 11:02:11.000 | Manish Smith |

```
SELECT
  i.owneridname,
  CAST(i.createdon AS date) as createdon,
  COUNT(i.svb_contactname) AS [Yes], 
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(i.svb_contactname) AS [No], 
  DATEPART(week, CAST(i.createdon AS date)) AS Week
FROM incident i
WHERE i.createdon >= DATEADD(day, -15, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
GROUP BY
  i.owneridname,
  CAST(i.createdon AS date)
ORDER BY
  Week DESC;
```

I get the following results:

| owneridname | createdon | Yes | No | Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 2023-06-25 | 2 | 0 | 26 |
| Michael grant | 2023-06-27 | 1 | 0 | 26 |
| Josh Gardner | 2023-06-24 | 26 | 35 | 26 |

The results I'd like to achieve:

| owneridname | Week Date | Yes | No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 2023-06-26 | 465 | 0 |
| Michael grant | 2023-06-26 | 323 | 0 |
| Josh Gardner | 2023-06-26 | 345 | 35 |

Comment: Can you add sample input data

Comment: Find monday, solutions here: [finding the start day (Monday) of the current week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936844/finding-the-start-day-monday-of-the-current-week). Use this value in aggregation and it seems to [work](https://dbfiddle.uk/S_KUqNvX).

Comment: The Q&A linked by Ponder shows the traditional first-day-of-week calculation using `DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, createdon), createdon)`. In SQL 2022, you can also use the `DATETRUNC()` function which also honors the `DATEFIRST` setting (`DATEDIFF` does not). Using `DATETRUNC(WEEK, createdon)` will also eliminate the time component without a separate `CAST ... AS DATE)`.

Comment: @TejaGoudKandula Sample data has been added above!

Comment: @DaleK Sample data has been added above

Comment: @hobosapien so what data is yes and no counting?

Comment: @DaleK Yes is non-NULL values, No is NULL

Comment: @hobosapien but your desired results don't match your sample data? That's the whole point of a [mre]

Comment: @DaleK Apologies - not sure I follow. The sample data is an example of the raw table data that is being queried in my original statement. Did I misinterpret and need to provide something else?

Comment: @hobosapien please read the definition of minimal reproducable example, you need sample data that when queried will produce the desired results.

Comment: @DaleK I ended up figuring it out on my own - I replaced the `CAST` function in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` functions with `DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) [week]` and it gives me results by week. However the week column returns a `2023-06-26 00:00:00.000` format. Is there a way to truncate it down to a mm/dd/yyy format?

Comment: Cast(value as date)? Keep in mind the minimal reproducible example for future questions

Comment: And feel free to add your answer as an answer and self-accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution with the following:

I replaced the

```
CAST(i.createdon AS date) as createdon
```

with `DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) [week]`
in the `SELECT` section from my original question, and

```
CAST(i.createdon AS date)
```

in the `GROUP BY` with:

```
DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0)
```

so it looks like this:

```
SELECT
  owneridname,
  DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) [week],
  COUNT(svb_contactname) AS [Yes], 
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(svb_contactname) AS [No]
FROM incident
WHERE createdon >= DATEADD(day, -15, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
  owneridname,
  DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0)
ORDER BY
  Week DESC;
```

Which now gives me the results of:

| owneridname | week | Yes | No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 2023-06-26 00:00:00.000 | 3 | 0 |
| Alexis Smith | 2023-06-26 00:00:00.000 | 0 | 12 |
| Andrea Smith | 2023-06-26 00:00:00.000 | 0 | 22 |
| Ashley Smith | 2023-06-26 00:00:00.000 | 0 | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to group the data by the week then your query should be:

```
SELECT
    i.owneridname,
    COUNT(i.svb_contactname) AS [Yes], 
    COUNT(*) - COUNT(i.svb_contactname) AS [No], 
    DATEPART(week, CAST(i.createdon AS date)) AS Week
FROM incident i
WHERE i.createdon >= DATEADD(day, -15, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
GROUP BY
    i.owneridname,
    DATEPART(WEEK, CAST(i.createdon AS DATE))
ORDER BY
    Week DESC;
```

Since, group by is on part of date `DATEPART`, had to remove the `i.createdon` from the `SELECT` query.

Comment: I get the same result as my original query statement - it returns the week number.

Comment: Yes, because Week Number is part of the query, but if you see the difference, the original query was grouped by date, whereas this query is grouped by week. I am not sure about what you're trying to achieve in `Yes` and `No` columns though.